# Multi-tenacy in Nifi (HDF)?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a HDF cluster composed of 3 nodes where Nifi is installed. My goal is to achieve multi-tenacy (maybe not the best word) on the Nifi level. Meaning that I want 2 things :

- Have different groups of users work on different flows repecting some access policy.
- Force the flows to be executed by different users on the unix system level. This might seem weird, but the destinations (hdfs, hive...) of my flows require different users to write on them. And having one nifi user can be problematic.

So far I have succeded in achieving the firt point using the security and authorization configuration in nifi. However, I don't know how to achieve the second point. Is it even possible ? Is there some sort of multiple instance configuration in hdf or nifi ? Can the flows be executed by different users on the unix system level ?

Any help is appreciated ...

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 3):

Apache NiFi supports multi-tenant authorization. To achieve multi-tenancy from a resource/system perspective you'll need to run multiple instances of NiFi. This will allow the separate processes to run as different users and be configured with different settings that affect resource consumption.

If the different dataflows managed by the different groups need to be connected, you can use a RemoteProcessGroup to point to the other instance to send and receive flowfiles.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for you answer. Knowing that I am using HDF, can one launch multiple instances of Nifi in a single HDF cluster and manage them through Ambari.